# How to move the focus from textarea to outside of it?

Tags: javascript, focus

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div id="some_div">
      <textarea></textarea>
  </div>

  <div id="other_div"></div>
</body>
```

Here's my code.
When clicking on the textarea, the cursor is focused on it.

And then, I just want to move the focus of the textarea to out of it with JavaScript code.
This will be same with clicking the other side of window, but **not with mouse.**

```
$('#other_div').focus()
$('#other_div').click()
```

The above things are not working.
How can I do this **only with javascript**?

Comment: other_side? that element in your html does not exist

Comment: don't you mean $('#other_**div**').focus() or $('#other_**div**').click()
?

Comment: .blur() perhaps? maybe .focusout() works as well

Comment: Oh, I edit my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the focus from an element by setting it on a different element (`$('#other_side').focus()`) but that element must be one that is **able to receive focus**.

A `div` (by default) is not an interactive control. Clicking on a div does nothing. You can't type into a div. It cannot receive the focus.

If you just want to remove the focus from everything, then you can `blur()` the element which **currently** has the focus.

```js
$("textarea").focus();
setTimeout(() => $('textarea').blur(), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```